# AWS: Attaching ASG to an EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, user-data, amazon-eks

I am trying to create an Autoscaling group with spot instances and attach it to the EKS cluster as worker nodes via terraform. I thought of giving the script to attach ASG to EKS cluster as userdata. Can someone help me with `userdata` or is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: You can create custom ASG with spot configuration rather than userdata?

Answer (score 1):

1.Userdata script for run ec2 instances into ASG

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${var.eks_name} --kubelet-extra-args '--node-labels=aws.asg-name=${var.eks_name}-workers'
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
         --stack  ${var.eks_name} \
         --resource NodeGroup  \
         --region ${var.aws_region}
```

2. kubectl apply -f ./configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::{aws_account_is}:role/eks-nodes
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```